# Disabling button after disable_with

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I use the `:disable_with` helper on a form button.

That form works via ajax. If the object is created successfully, I want to keep that button disabled. So in my `create.js.erb` file I have: `$('#my-button').disabled = true;`.

However, it doesn't work (works fine in the console though).

I suspect its interfering with Rails' JS for the disable_with helper. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) method to set the `disabled` property of the button. In your case, the code should be

```
$('#my-button').prop('disabled', true);
```

To prevent the `:disable_with` helper from enabling the button again, remove the `data-disable-with` attribute from the button:

```
$('#my-button').removeAttr('data-disable-with');
```

Comment: ah, thanks for that. I'm actually using plain javascript and the setAttribute() method in my actual code. Good to know how to do it in jQuery though. Unfortunately it still doesn't wokr.

Comment: Oh I just got what you meant by "works fine in the console". How about removing the `data-disable-with` property of the button, or changing its `id` in `create.js.erb`? This is just my guess, perhaps the `disable_with` helper relies on one of the two properties above.