# Rails Ajax form_for is enabling multiple submissions (cannot disable submit button)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, form-for

I have an issue with an ajax form I use for rendering errors, but it's allowing the user to submit basically an unlimited number of time as long as they keep mashing the submit button. What happens is when the user presses the submit button, it grays out for a fraction of a second with the disable_with text and then becomes clickable again. The user can then keep pressing and making post requests. Only when the user stops does the redirect happen. I've searched through basically all the answers for this particular problem, and they don't seem to work for me. I was wondering if someone could help.

I've tried using javascript to disable the button and using data: {disable_with: "..."}.

Here is my .html.erb code right as of now:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
  <%= form_for [@group, @task], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.label :priority %>
    <%= f.text_field :priority, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.label :user %>
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@group.options_for_user), {}, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= f.submit "Create Task", class: "btn btn-primary new-task-button", data: {disable_with: "Creating task..."} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is my controller code for the task new and create actions

```
def new
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @task = Task.new
end

def create
  new_user = User.find(task_params.delete(:user_id))
  @task = Task.new(to_update)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      @group.tasks << @task
      new_user.tasks << @task
      format.html {redirect_to @group}
      TasksChannel.broadcast_to(@group, {action: "create", data: @task, user: new_user}) 
    else
      @errors = @task.errors
      format.js {render :file => "layouts/errors.js.erb"}
    end
  end
end

def task_params
  return params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :priority, :user_id)
end
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and it's so frustrating. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What's `to_update `?

Comment: Sorry, meant to delete that. I'll update it. It's just the filtered strong parameter, i.e. params.require(:task).permit(....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that the html in your page has that attribute. Open your browser at localhost:3000 and open the developer toolbar to check that html element.
2. Write some Jquery in your `applicationscript.js` file  and test if the problem is solved. Maybe there is some conflict with turbo-links or something else

   ```
   $('#my-button').prop('disabled', true);
   ```

[Disabling button after disable_with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369337/disabling-button-after-disable-with#16369705)

3. Test the effect also on a simple jquery project without ruby on rails..

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If anyone comes along the same problem, I ended up having to disable the button and disabling the data-disable in my create.js.erb. Then, because the redirect doesn't work for some reason in the controller, I redirected using javascript.

Comment: @JerryChen Ok. not easy.. great!